# How to manage API requests in multiusers app in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app when user add object it execute one API request to third party site. For single user is ok to send the request immediately. But API calls are limited by 3 per second. So, when qtt of users will increase it'll be a trouble. I suggested that ActiveJob + Sidekiq will do the work, but how to get results when job is done? 
My code for one user:

```
controller.rb
def create
wall = get_request(code_constructor({params for constructor },[]))
end

module CommonMods

  def code_constructor(meth_name, meth_params, code) 
    param_str = []
    meth_params.each_pair do |name, value|
      param_str << '"' + name.to_s + '":'+ value.to_s
    end
    param_str = param_str.join(',')
    code << meth_name + '({' + param_str + '})'
  end

  def get_request(code) 
    i = 0
    result = []
    while i < code.size
      part_code = code.slice(i, i + 25)
      if part_code.size >1
        part_code = part_code.join(',')
      else
        part_code = part_code[0]
      end
      url='https://api.site.com/method/'
      uri = URI.parse(url)
      parameters =  {'code' => "return [#{part_code}];"}
      response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, parameters) 
      result = result + JSON.parse(response.body)['response']
      i += 25
    end
    result
  end
end
```

How to execute get_request method in queue with `code` param and proceed with received response in the controller? Or maybe it have different way to make it?

Comment: What will your controller do when it gets the result?

Comment: @Yang It'll render the view with received data and users will interact with it.